# window hashchange listner calling after being added

Tags: javascript, hashchange

```
overlay.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = 'overlay';

    var close = function(){
        //do some stuff
        window.removeEventListener('hashchange', close);
    }

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', close, false);
}
```

Basically, as soon as I click the link, the hash is updated, and the close function is calling. The close function shouldn't be bound until AFTER the hash is changed. Why is the `close` function being called as soon as the listener is added, and how do I prevent it. Testing in Chrome, latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because Javascript is synchronous, so when you set `window.location.hash`, the `window.onhashchange` method will not run until the `onclick` function currently running finishes. Does that make sense? So you set the `.hash` value, then bind a `hashchange` event...right after binding, the `onhashchange` event actually fires. So that in turn calls `close`. Try putting `console.log` statements throughout your code to see the order of execution.

**UPDATE**:

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the order of things: http://jsfiddle.net/jmWDY/

Notice how the original `onhashchange` function is called first (after your function is finished), then your new binding (which is `close`). I hope this helped!